# How to revert committed changes from git

Tags: git

I had committed the changes in git. But, didn't push it. How can i revert my changes from commit.

And is there any chance to stash the single file in git

Can any one please help me

Comment: Did you try to read some tutorial to git? These are two major topics on most of them. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo the last Git commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/undo-the-last-git-commit)

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options:

- Add a commit to revert this one
- Actually delete this one (which is possible since you didn't push it yet)

To add a new commit to undo, you just need ton run `git revert <sha1>`, where `<sha1>` is the commit you don't want.

To actually delete this commit you could run

```
git rebase -i <sha1>^
```

it will open your text editor with a list of commits. Juste delete the line with the commit you don't want, save, and exit. Git will then rewrite your history, removing this commit.